# asus smartdotctor "can not find graphics card information"

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, graphics-card

I am not sure that this is the place I can ask questions like this, but I'll give it a try.

I have a Windows 7 64bit, new graphic card ASUS ENGTX260 MATRIX, installed latest graphics drivers nv19045_Win7Vista64 and ASUS Smart Doctor version 5.44. Unfortunately, after the required reboot when the smartdoctor is starting, I get an error "can not find graphics card information".

I tried google, but none of that "run as admin"/"use compatibility" doesn't help. Perhaps here can I find my answers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest drivers from ASUS finally work.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix is an ROG board, smartdoctor does not work with ROG cards.
Use ASUS itracker instead (according to ASUS site):

http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?SLanguage=en-us&product=9&model=ENGTX275 Series&type=map&f_type=14

Cheers, John

Comment: Nope, i installed itracker I had on the DVD that came with graphics and got "Can not find Support Card !" for a change..